# Kendo Objects lose function and style

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm having trouble with some kendo objects, specifically buttons, dropdown lists, and text boxes.  My situation is this: I have a partial view that loads a list of parts and a list of projects.  Each item is the list contains a link that opens a kendo Window that loads a partial view of information about the part or project.  All parts share a window, but the information is updated depending on the part, and all projects share a window, where all the information is updated depending on the project.  The window is instantiated on the partial view that contains the list of parts, but is not visible until a part/project is clicked.  Data is then loaded from a separate partial view onto the window, the window then  opens.  Each window contains kendo buttons, kendo text boxes, and kendo dropdown lists.

On first load, both project and part links work properly.  They continue to work until the user opens up the other type of link, either part or project.  Both windows then stop functioning.  The window opens, but all of the kendo objects lose their function.  For example, a drop down list becomes a text box, a button takes on a flat blue look, and the sheet loses its style from CSS.  I use kendo objects many other times in this project successfully, so I know its something with this view.  I checked the names and IDs of the windows and all objects in the windows, none are shared.  I also changed the name of javascript functions that are in the partial views(I Know this is bad practice but I never figured out proper way) to be different from each other.  The issue persists.

I don't have enough reputation to post pictures, and most image hosting websites are blocked at work, so i can't post any visual aid.

Below is the code for one of the windows.

```
 <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:central">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Kendo.Button.Name("test1").Content("Add    Costs").Events(Sub(events) events.Click("enterActualInfo"))
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.Kendo.Button.Name("test2").Content("View Change History").Events(Sub(events) events.Click("showProjectHistory"))
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.Kendo.Button.Name("test3").Content("GPC/Target").Events(Sub(events) events.Click("addGPC"))
                </td>
            </tr>                
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code that opens the windows

```
    function sendProjInfo(projNum) {

    var projectWindow = $("#custProjWindow").data("kendoWindow")
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("getCustProjInfo", "Home")",
        data: { custProjNumber: projNum },
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            projectWindow.content(result).open()

        }
    })
}

//when a part number is clicked, open a new window that has thats part information
function sendPartInfo(partNumber) {

    var partWindow = $("#partWindow").data("kendoWindow")
   $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("getPartInfo", "Home")",
        data: {partNumber: partNumber},
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            partWindow.content(result).open();
        }
    })

}
```

and here is the instantiation of the windows.

```
@Html.Kendo.Window.Name("custProjWindow").Title("Edit Customer Project").Draggable.Resizable.Actions(Sub(actions) actions.Minimize.Maximize.Close()).Visible(False)

@Html.Kendo.Window.Name("partWindow").Title("Edit Part").Draggable.Resizable.Actions(Sub(actions) actions.Minimize.Maximize.Close()).Visible(False)
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.  I'm happy to post more information if it will help solve the issue.  Thanks in advance.

-Eric

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I don't think thats an issue because its reloading new information into the same window.  So new buttons aren't created, just values of objects are being changed. Also, opening and closing only one type of window in sequence worked properly, it was only when window types alternated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's easy to determine the cause: double id's. When you open the first there's no problem as buttons are #test1, #test2 and #test3, but when you load another one those id's are repeated into the same page

You should change your partial view so the name of the buttons is dynamic and unique:

From:

```
@Html.Kendo.Button.Name("test1").Content("Add    Costs").Events(Sub(events) events.Click("enterActualInfo"))
```

To:

```
@Html.Kendo.Button.Name("test1_" + ViewBag.someId).Content("Add    Costs").Events(Sub(events) events.Click("enterActualInfo"))
```

In your controller, you have an action that returns your partialView, right? In there, you must pass the unique id that will differentiate each partial from the others.

```
public PartialViewResult _YourPartialView()
{
    ViewBag.someId = variableName; // this should be something like a model Id or something.
    return PartialView();
}
```

You can use a variable in the controller or send something via javascript when you click the link that loads the partial views.

Answer (score 1):

I spent many many hours looking into this problem before posting this question.  Only minutes after posting the question, I fixed it.

For anyone else with this issue, or a similar issue:

- Ensure that no objects share an ID.  Apparently this is bad.
- If any events call a JS function, ensure that they are spelled correctly and in 
  quotation marks.
- If any events call a JS function, ensure the function is loaded before the objects that call it.  I simply placed my functions above the buttons and it fixed all of my issues.  I'm sure theres a better practice that I have yet to learn, but its a start.
- always check your browsers debugger!  There's always valuable information in there.

Best of luck to anyone having similar issues.